# mosquitto.so: undefined symbol: _zend_hash_add in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, apache, mqtt, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to get Mosquitto PHP library on RaspberryPi working.  Every time I restart Apache2 I get the line /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mosquitto.so: undefined symbol: _zend_hash_add in Unknown on line 0.

I thought it was due to loading the .so too early so I moved it to the back of  the .ini files.  (30-mosquitto.ini and nothing else is 30-).

I'm guessing that the zend framework is not in a path somewhere, but I can't find it.

My question is:
Where does the Zend library get loaded at and is there a line missing from apache2.conf for Zend?

-Jim

Comment: This has nothing to do with Zend Framework. The "zend" in the error comes from Zend Engine, which is part of PHP. The issue is with the mosquitto library itself - check that it is compatible with your PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's response was on the money.  I had both PHP5 and PHP 7.0 installed.  I was building to 7 but my Apache2 server was pointing to PHP5.  I pointed my Apache2 to PHP7 and that did the trick.